# Converting an fp-ts Either to an Effect Either

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I have been using [fp-ts](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/) for some time. Lately, I have been thinking about migrating some parts of my codebase to using [Effect](https://effect.website/) instead. I'm looking looking for bridges between the two. One of the first obstacles I have run into, is that the `Either` data structures used by two libraries differ slightly from each other. What would be a good way of converting between the two?

```js
import * as E from '@effect/data/Either'
import * as F from 'fp-ts/Either'

const fe: F.Either<string, number> = F.right(123)
// @ts-expect-error not assignable
const ee: E.Either<string, number> = fe
```

Comment: Are they class instances of just objects? Do they have the same JS implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you would need to destructure the fp-ts Either and reconstruct the Effect Either.

Something like this:

```
pipe(
  fe,
  F.matchW(E.left, E.right)
)
```

This would convert an "fp-ts Left" -> "Effect Left" and an "fp-ts Right" -> "Effect Right"